# GMaps displaying markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to load markers from MySql database (i used a php file which converted the data giving xml output) but I only see the map. After reading posts on StackOverflow I still don't know how make it work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=true"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
function initialize()
{
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapka"), {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.109612,17.036276),
    zoom:12,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

    downloadUrl("dane.php", function(data)
    {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
    {
        var nazwa = markers[i].getAttribute("nazwa");
        var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
        var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point
        });
    }
});
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}
function doNothing() {}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

<div id="mapka" style="width:700px;height:500px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The XML looks like this:

```
<dane>
    <marker lat="51.110287" lon="17.062647" nazwa="Hello_1" address="Street_1"/>
    <marker lat="51.111807" lon="17.058012" nazwa="Hello_2" address="Street_2"/>
</dane>
```

Comment: @Dr.Molle, this solution doesn't work

Comment: then you'll have to show your function `downloadUrl` , because it's not defined somewhere in the code above

Comment: data.responseXML contains what? When it's not a XML-document, let the PHP-script send a XML-content-type-header

Answer (score 1):

You try to access an attribute `lng` , but the attribute defined for the markers inside the XML is `lon`